# In GAP, how can we write functions whose signatures have optional variables?

Tags: math-software, gap

We know that some GAP functions present additional options in their signature. For example, consider the `IsomorphicSubgroups` function, if we set `findall` to `false`, it only finds one isomorphic subgroup and stops, e.g.,

```
gap> IsomorphicSubgroups(SmallGroup(8,3),SmallGroup(4,2):findall:=false);
[ [ f1, f2 ] -> [ f1*f3, f1 ] ]
```

I've used `PageSource(IsomorphicSubgroups)` but have failed to figure out how to do it. I would be glad if someone can explain how we can write such functions by giving a simple example.

I also wonder about whether we can define functions sharing the same name with different signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm, not sure what a signature would be, but what is used here is an option. The code for `IsomorphicSubgroups` calls

```
if ValueOption("findall")=false then
```

to go in the case of only finding one subgroup, otherwise in one to find all. If no option is given when calling the function `ValueOption("findall")` would return `fail`.
You can use any string as your own option, and there is no need to formally declare it.

Comment: By a signature, I mean the parameters of the function. For instance, can we define two different functions named the same but having different numbers of parameters?

Comment: Thanks. Then it actually is not part of the signature. If you want to create a variable-number-of-arguments function, you can use the special variable name `arg`.

Comment: Actually in "modern" GAP, you can also write e.g. `function(x, more...)` to declare a function taking at least 1 argument; the first argument is stored in `x`, any further arguments stored as a list in `more`. This works with any number of "fixed" arguments

Comment: @MaxHorn That's great! Thank you.